# iOS Search in one Array, match by Index from another

Tags: ios, arrays, uitableview, search, uisearchbar

I have two arrays:

```
NSMutableArray *moviesArray;
NSMutableArray *directorsArray;
moviesArray = [@"movie01",@"movie02",@"movie03",@"movie04"];
directorsArray = [@"director01",@"director02",@"director03",@"director04"];
```

I am showing this in a Table View. Each Cell has a Title Label and a Director Label.

```
cell.titleLabel.text = [moviesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.directorLabel.text = [directorsarray objectatIndex:indexPath.row];
```

I am using a Search Bar to search for movie titles so I do:

```
//Search Filter Code
- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope {
    NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[c] %@", searchText];
    searchResults = [moviesArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];
    NSLog(@"Search Results: %@", searchResults);
}

-(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString {
[self filterContentForSearchText:searchString
                           scope:[[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles]
                                  objectAtIndex:[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar
                                                 selectedScopeButtonIndex]]];

return YES;
}
```

And then in my Cell:

```
if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
    cell.pdmTitle.text = [searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[...] }
```

All this works. My question is, each movie, has a corresponding Director in directorsArray.
How can I do to show the matching director in my cell?

Meaning, if I search for movie 03, titleLabel.text should be movie03 and directorLabel.text should be director03.

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: I will not recommend this approach for your situation. You should opt for a custom model class where you can have two properties to store the movie name and director name. Then during search you can filter using movie name and can directly populate the director name from same model object without worrying about the correct index in another array.

Comment: I know, however I was just trying to learn a bit more about Arrays and different approaches to some situations. Indeed a Custom Model class would be the best option.
Thank you very much, Gandalf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSString *correspondingDirector = [directorsArray objectAtIndex: [moviesArray indexOfObject:@"Movie you are searching"]];
```

Comment: In this case, indexOfObject was what the sort of solution I was looking for. Thank you very much, it helped a lot!

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered using a single `NSDictionary` instead of using two `NSArrays`?

For example:

```
NSDictionary *movies=@{@"movie1":@"director1",@"movie2":@"director2"};
```

This way you can always know the director of a movie by simply doing:

```
[movies objectForKey:@"movie1"];
```

If you want to store more info about each movie, then the best approach would be to use an `array` of `dictionaries`, for example:

```
NSDictionary *movie=@{@"MovieName":@"Norbit",@"Director":@"Eddie Murphy",@"Language":@"English"};
NSArray *movies=@[movie];
```

Comment: Yes, I´ve considered a Dictionary, but if I later want to add another field, like for example, actors, a Dictionary would not be the best option.

Comment: You can definitely add an array of actors to the 'movies' dictionary. But yes, the best option would be to use a custom model class.

Answer (score 0):

According to your code add this :

```
   if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
cell.pdmTitle.text = [searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
 // line to add:
 NSString *director = [directorsArray objectAtIndex:[moviesArray indexOfObject:cell.pdmTitle.text]];
 [...] }
```